# Sprockets can't find javascripts in flot-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, flot, sprockets

I tried to use the [foot-rails gem](https://github.com/Vasfed/flot-rails)  to install flot but was unsuccessful.

I added `gem "flot-rails"` to my gemfile and executed `bundle install`

I then added

```
//= require jquery.flot
//= require jquery.flot.resize
```

to my /app/assets/javascripts/application.js file

I verified that the gem installed properly (gem show flot-rails) and found that the javascripts were all in the vendor directory of the gem but my app reports

> couldn't find file 'jquery.flot'
>     (in ...path/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:12)

I chose to just install the files manually into my assets directory but I'd like to know what's wrong with my sprockets.

Why ca't Sprockets resolve the references?

Answer (score 7):

Well, don't I feel stupid.

I needed to restart the web server after `bundle install`

Comment: Dont forget to accept your answer.  I was going to mention that, but thought you already did.